# Calculating number of records in database which has a value of Enum

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, enums

I want to build a query to count how many elements are there in the database have certain value of Enum
I use this query

```
Grower = db.Sites.Count(x => x.Categories == SiteCategories.Grower && x.Status == EntityStatus.Default)
```

but It doesn't work correct, can anyone help ?

Comment: What about SiteCategories.Grower.ToString()? What is the datatype and value of x.Categories?

Comment: `doesn't work correct` doesn't help much... wrong result, not compiling, exception thrown ?

Comment: Do you get an exception? Please post the exception details and stack trace.

Comment: I guess you need a cast like  `(int) SiteCategories.Grower`

Comment: How is SiteCategories.Grower saved in your DB? as int or a string?

Comment: I would ask : what is the type of property `Categories` in your entity class (same for `Status`)

Answer (score 1):

> In Entity Framework, an enumeration can have the following underlying
> types:  Byte, Int16,  Int32,  Int64 , or SByte.

Take a look at: [Enumeration Support in Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/29/enumeration-support-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Which means you will need to use the int value to search the database unless your saving the text somehow so you will need to use `SiteCategories.Grower.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

If the value in the database is the string, you'll need to call `.ToString()` on the enum to compare it - otherwise it will compare the value.

```
 var myCount = db.Sites.Count(x => x.Categories == SiteCategories.Grower.ToString() && x.Status == EntityStatus.Default);
```